# what the function does and its application?

Tags: image, sse, intrinsics

I was asked this question in an interview. Though I can read what the instructions does below but I was not able to figure out the application of this code and its exact usage.

```
  dr  = _mm_set1_epi16(6);
  fr  =  fr1;
  dr  = _mm_add_epi16(dr, fr);
  fr  = _mm_or_si128(fr, fr2);
  dr  = _mm_add_epi16(dr, fr);
  fr  = _mm_or_si128(fr, fr3);
  dr  = _mm_add_epi16(dr, fr);
  fr  = _mm_or_si128(fr, fr4);
  dr  = _mm_add_epi16(dr, fr);
  fr  = _mm_or_si128(fr, fr5);
  dr  = _mm_add_epi16(dr, fr);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

The interviewer skill set belongs to Video processing or image processing algorithms. So I am tagging the image processing.